# How to select the last two integers in an IF statement as a true or false statement?

Tags: javascript

if (ID.equals())

I would like to know as to what code to write in the parentheses to make the statement true only if the last two numbers match the numbers provided in the IF statement.

Comment: what do you mean by last two integers?

Comment: What does this question mean? Do you mean the last two digits of an integer?

Comment: By the last 2 integers I mean the last 2 numbers . For example 25 from the number 123425

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ID is a number;

```
if (parseInt(ID.toString().slice(-2)) == 22) return true
```

Assuming ID is a string

```
if (parseInt(ID.slice(-2)) == 22) return true
```

Answer (score 0):

`var variable =((num1 == 1) && (num2 == 2))?true:false;`